# Retrieve Random String from Core Data in Swift

Tags: ios, core-data, swift, nsfetchrequest

I've searched for this answer but have come up empty handed. For some reason I'm drawing a blank on how to retrieve a random entry from a Core Data String attribute. I have everything else working - create, update, delete... but can't seem to get a handle on getting a random entry from the stack.

Feeling confused on this. Here is my code from my table view controller that mostly manages the core data.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class TaskManagerViewController: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

    let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

    var fetchedResultController: NSFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        fetchedResultController = getFetchedResultController()
        fetchedResultController.delegate = self
        fetchedResultController.performFetch(nil)
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
        if segue.identifier == "edit" {
            let cell = sender as UITableViewCell
            let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)
            let taskController:TaskDetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as TaskDetailViewController
            let task:Tasks = fetchedResultController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as Tasks
            taskController.task = task
        }
    }


    func getFetchedResultController() -> NSFetchedResultsController {
        fetchedResultController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: taskFetchRequest(), managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        return fetchedResultController
    }

    func taskFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Tasks")
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "desc", ascending: true)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        return fetchRequest
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // #pragma mark - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        let numberOfSections = fetchedResultController.sections?.count
        return numberOfSections!
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let numberOfRowsInSection = fetchedResultController.sections?[section].numberOfObjects
        return numberOfRowsInSection!
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
            let task = fetchedResultController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as Tasks
            cell.textLabel.text = task.desc
            return cell
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let managedObject:NSManagedObject = fetchedResultController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as NSManagedObject
        managedObjectContext?.deleteObject(managedObject)
        managedObjectContext?.save(nil)
    }

    func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController!) {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean a random string?  Do you mean to select a random object from your fetched objects?

Comment: Yes I mean select a random object from the core data, just happens to be of the type string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the code that ultimately delivered the results I was looking for:

(I'm new at stack overflow so not sure how to select correct answer here.)

```
func randomTask() -> Tasks {

        let count = UInt32(fetchedResultController.fetchedObjects!.count)
        let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(count))
        var results = fetchedResultController.fetchedObjects![index] as Tasks
        answerLabel.text = results.valueForKey("desc") as NSString
        return results
    }
```

Comment: Do I select my answer which works or Paul's answer which led me to the working code?

Comment: I think it would be fair to up vote Paul's, and accept your own.

Comment: That's what I'll end up doing. But I need 15 rep to up vote and two days to select my answer. What's the best way to get rep going? Answer questions I assume.

Answer (score 2):

```
func randomTask() -> Tasks {

   let count=UInt32(fetchedResultController.fetchedObjects!.count) 
   let index=Int(arc4random_uniform(count))
   return fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects[index] as Tasks
}
```

Comment: I had tried something similar and ran into the same problem as I'm getting with your code... the constant count spits out an error that [AnyObject]? does not have a member named count.

Comment: Ok, you just need to unwrap the optional

Comment: Paul can you show me the code that would work, I've unwrapped all possible optionals and also used if let syntax and I'm still getting errors like the value does;t support sequencing, etc.

Comment: Sorry.  I'm not really a fan of Swift.  I find all of this optional malarky more trouble than it is worth.

Comment: Thanks anyhow Paul. Still need a solution fellow Stackers.

Comment: @Paulw11's `let count = ` line works fine for me, but you need to have the same unwrapping of fetchedObjects in the `return ...` line: `return fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects![index] as Tasks`